# push certain elements into array php

Tags: php

I want to know that is there a way to insert certain elements of an array into a new array. I mean I have an array containing 10 objects. Each object has 3 or four fields for example id, name , age , username. now I want to insert the id's of all the objects into the new array with a single call.Is there anyway to do that.

```
$array = [ 
  [0] => [
      id   =>      
      name =>
  ],
  [1] = > [
      id   =>
      name =>
  ]
]
```

and so on now I want to insert all the id's of all the object into a new array with a single call. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why does it have to be a "single call"? That's a strange requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function.

Here is your solution:-

```
 $ids = array_map( function( $arr ){
                    return $arr["id"];
                }, $arr );

 echo '<pre>'; print_r($ids);
```

Comment: can you tell me just one more thing that if I have multiple arrays, can I give all the arrays after the call back ??

Comment: If all arrays have same structure then first merge them. Is array_map working for you?

Comment: I have not used it but I think it will do what I want. Let me check

Comment: I know I can merge them but just for knowledge can I give it multiple arrays having same structure ?

Comment: No you can not pass multiple array within same function for same operation.

Comment: You can use 'use' keyword in this function. Using that keyword you can pass additional array or data to this function for performing any operation.

Answer (score 0):

A basic foreach loop will do the job just fine

```
$firstArray = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'abc'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'def'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'gh'
  )
);

$onlyIds = array();
$onlyKeys = array();

//To get the array value 'id'
foreach($firstArray as $value){
  $onlyIds[] = $value['id'];
}

//To get the array keys
foreach($firstArray as $key => $value){
  $onlyKeys[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: I know a simple for loop will be fine but it's a requirement that I do it with a single call

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_walk which could be considered a "single call"

```
$array = array(0 => array('id', 'name', 'age'), 1 => array('id', 'name', 'age'));
array_walk($array, function($item, $key) {
    // $key is 0 or 1
    // $item is either id, name, age
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [array_column](http://php.net/array_column).

```
$arr = [ ['id' => 1, 'username' => 'a'], ['id' => 2, 'username' => 'b'] ];
$ids = array_column($arr, 'id')
$ids == [1, 2]
```